# Adding Unittest/Code Coverage to already existin Application

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have done with OClusterMapView ,now I want to add unit tests to it. Somebody told to add Test.h and Test.m files to my application ,but I am (un)Clear with this concept.Can anyone Please Help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at apple's [xcode unit testing documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/00-About_Unit_Testing/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143). Additionally here's a great [sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneUnitTests/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008868) of theirs. The basics are add a unit test target, start adding tests.

Once you get beyond the basics you may need something along the lines of [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/) and [ILTesting](https://github.com/InfiniteLoopDK/ILTesting) is a great tool also.

Comment: Thanks for the response,I will try them.

Comment: How can we write our own test cases? Is there any scenario to follow?

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on unit testing and systems integration testing in general. For me, I prefer to test my 'network layer' code as systems integration tests.